# background color on <span> when hovering interior text

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm creating some images that when you hover them they display some text on top, so far it all works quite well but the problem I now have is how to keep the background black while hovering the h2.. any help is greatly appreciated

see a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/buNBm/2/

This is what I have

```
<a href="#">
  <h2>Some Text</h2>
  <span>
    <img src="http://www.sheridanrogers.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/American-pancakes.jpg"/>
  </span>
</a>
```

and css

```
img {width:250px;}

a:hover h2 {display: block!important;}

a h2 { position: absolute; top:0 ; display: none; color: #fff;}

a span {display: inline-block;}

a:hover span {background: #000}

a span img:hover, a span:hover img {visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/buNBm/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply it, using only the h2 tag :

```
<a href="#">
  <h2>Some Text</h2>
  <img src="http://www.sheridanrogers.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/American-pancakes.jpg"/>
</a>
```

And for the CSS

```
a { position: relative; display: inline-block }

a img {
    width:250px;
}

a h2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
}

a:hover h2 {
    display: block;
}
```

see the demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/jiceb/xsFmA/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a  href="#">
  <h2 onmouseout="document.getElementById('123').style.backgroundColor='white';document.getElementById('456').style.visibility='visible';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('123').style.backgroundColor='#000';document.getElementById('456').style.visibility='hidden';">Some Text</h2>
  <span id='123'>
    <img id='456' src="http://www.sheridanrogers.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/American-pancakes.jpg"/>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a rule to style the `span` on `h2:hover`:

```
h2:hover + span img,
a span img:hover,
a span:hover img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/buNBm/5/).

But you could, just as easily, replace all those selectors with:

```
a:hover span img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/buNBm/7/).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `visibility: hidden;` on `img` while hovering over `a`

**[SEE THE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/buNBm/3/)**

```
a:hover span img 

{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```